# SQL server 2008 R2 - Hardware Requirement

Tags: sql-server-2008, hardware

I have to give SQL server hardware requirement for the below specifications

1. Number of instances <= 5
2. Number of databases per instance > 50
3. Number of concurrent users per instance <= 2000
4. Daily transaction size of data will be <= 500 MB

I need to know below things

1. Type of RAID
2. RAM
3. Number of processors
4. except this, is there anything that i need to focus on hardware requirements?

Someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on the amount of traffic a user generates. according to the transaction size and related concurrency it looks like users are idle most of the time. 
=> measure it instead of estimating it

my own experience with sql performance:
you can reach very high concurrency if the queries to be answered are very efficient and fast - if only a small part of the queries are long running and require much cpu you need much more powerful hardware than answering small queries that are always the same (when query cache hits).

if the databases are not too big, it's always good to be able to hold large parts of them in memory - I/O is slow and expensive. concurrency that requires I/O may create a serious bottleneck.
saying so: having enough memory and being able to hold most data there may avoid several possible bottlenecks.
talking about storage in general: faster is better. focus on low response times  if you're not writing too much sequential data.
using local storage i would recomment raid10 with at least 4 fast disks (more is always better).

speaking about cores you may also take licensing in concern - don't start with less than 4 cores (if single socket) or 8 cores (on dual socket). don't assign virtual cores (hyper-threading)

when using virtualization (e.g. hyper-v) we saw some deployments where using dynamic memory made sql not using the possible memory - switching to fixed assignment made it use the whole memory and performing much better overall.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Answering garbage questions only encourages them to be asked.

Comment: you're propably right :-)

Comment: HopelessN00b - Garbage Question? what does it mean?

Comment: it refers to the fact that there is no way to recomment a configuration without knowing the demands of an application. a sql can handle thousands of queries in parallel - if fast answered or only a few if quite complex. you need to know the demands of the application and have to scale on this use case. sometimes its suitable to measure on a smaller workload and extrapolate on these measurements - thus beeing said don't expect to scale linear as additional concurreny generates additonal overhead